# Is it true that $ \sum_{n=m+1}^{k-1} A(n) \int_{n}^{n+1} f'(t)dt = \sum_{n=m+1}^{k-1} \int_{n}^{n+1} A(t) f'(t)dt $?

Tags: number-theory, definite-integrals, summation, proof-explanation

In Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol, section 4.3 (Relations to $\vartheta(x)$ and $\pi(x)$), there is the following step in the proof for Theorem 4.2 (Abel's identity):

$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^{k-1} A(n) \int_{n}^{n+1} f'(t)dt = \sum_{n=m+1}^{k-1} \int_{n}^{n+1} A(t) f'(t)dt.
$$

Here $k$ and $m$ are integers. They were defined to be $ k = [x] $ and $ m = [y] $ where $ 0 < y < x $ and $ f $ has a continuous derivative on the interval $ [y, x] $.

The function $ A $ is defined as follows: For any arithmetical function $ a(n) $ let $ A(x) = \sum_{n \le x} a(n) $ where $ A(x) = 0 $ if $ x < 1 $.

How does this step hold true?

Comment: I don't have the book at hand. What is $A(t)$?

Comment: Note that by definition of $A$ we have $A(t)=A(n)$ for all $t\in[n,n+1)$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Added the definition of $ A $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $a(n)$ in the definition of
\begin{align*}
A(x)= \sum_{n \le x} a(n) 
\end{align*}
is an arithmetic function $a:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$. This means, that for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$A(x)=A(k)=const.\qquad\qquad k\leq x<k+1$$
It follows
\begin{align*}
A(k)=A(k)\int_0^1dx=\int_0^1 A(x)\,dx
\end{align*}